# Why does my code intended to stop Rigidbody from sliding prevent player from jumping?

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I have the following code which gives a Rigidbody capsule the ability to move and jump (if on layer `Ground`).

After Player stops input, the Rigidbody slides. I wanted to massively reduce sliding by adding `GroundStopSlide()` which is intended to set Rigidbody velocity to zero if it detects sliding greater than a certain magnitude when Player lets hand off keyboard.

I am finding that this works mostly as intended, BUT: If player jumps while standing still, the jump does not reach its normal height. It is a stunted jump.

Why might this be happening? Thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move1 : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public Rigidbody r;

    //Base Movement
    public float horizontalInput;
    public float verticalInput;
    public Vector3 movDirection;
    public float speed = 20f;

    //Ground Check
    public bool isGrounded = true;    
    public Transform groundCheckTransform;
    public float groundCheckRadius = 0.25f;
    public LayerMask groundLayerMask;

    //Jump
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public bool isJumping;
    public float stopSlideSpeed = 1f;

    void Awake()
    {
        groundLayerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
        r = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();    
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        movDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput).normalized;

        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            print("Not Grounded");
            this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.cyan);
        }
        else
        {
            this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.white);
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }     
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            GroundStopSlide();
        }

        r.AddForce(movDirection * (speed + 10f), ForceMode.Force);

        if (isJumping == true)
        {
            Jump();
        }

        GroundCheck();        
    }


    public void GroundCheck()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheckTransform.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayerMask);
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            r.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, jumpForce, 0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        isJumping = false;
    }
  
    void GroundStopSlide()
    {
        if (r.velocity.magnitude >= stopSlideSpeed && movDirection == Vector3.zero)
            r.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation yet to comment, so will have to put this as an answer.

I think the problem is due to the GroundCheck staying set to true after you've started your jump.  The impulse to the rigidbody from the jump will probably set the y velocity to some positive value, but the groundcheck is still triggering (maybe something to do with the radius of the sphere you're using) before Unity does the vertical movement.  The next fixed update frame will see that the isGrounded is still true and set the y velocity to 0 in the GroundStopSlide method, thus stunting the jump.

You can probably avoid this by testing whether you have zero or negative y velocity in the groundcheck method (if you're moving up, you don't really need to check if you're grounded still).